# Test class for below wrapper class in salesforce

Tags: code-coverage, wrapper-class

```
public class SortingDates {
    Public List<SortingDatesWrapper> cList {get;set;}
    public SortingDates()  {
    cList = new List<SortingDatesWrapper>();
        List<Royalty_Report__c> aList =[SELECT Submission_End_Date__c  from Royalty_Report__c ORDER BY Submission_End_Date__c ASC];
        List<Instalment__c> bList =[SELECT Due_Date__c  from  Instalment__c ORDER BY Due_Date__c ASC];
        for(Royalty_Report__c rr : aList){
         cList.add(new SortingDatesWrapper(rr));   
        }
        for(Instalment__c inv : bList){
         cList.add(new SortingDatesWrapper(inv));   
        }
       cList.sort();
        for(Integer i =0; i< cList.size(); i++)
        {
       if(cList[0].d1== aList[i].Submission_End_Date__c) 
       system.debug('Royalty Report'); 
       if(cList[0].d2== bList[i].Due_Date__c)
       system.debug('Installment');
    } 
  }       
    //Wrapper Class
    public class  SortingDatesWrapper{
        Public Date d1{get;set;}
        Public Date d2{get;set;}
       public SortingDatesWrapper(Date d1,Date d2) {
            this.d1 = d1;
            this.d2 = d2;
        }
        Public SortingDatesWrapper (Royalty_Report__c rr){

        }
        Public SortingDatesWrapper (Instalment__c inv) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post of what you have tried so far and what error you are getting

Comment: Hello,I am new to salesforce.I need help in writing test class for the above wrapper class.

Comment: Please go through https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_testing